# What are the differences between key, key_hash, address, contract and signature in Michelson?

Tags: michelson, contract, address, key, signature

There is a [related question](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/776/address-key-and-key-hash), but the differences are still not clear. These five types are mentioned in the [Michelson whitedoc](https://tezos.gitlab.io/whitedoc/michelson.html) with the following definitions:

- `address`: An untyped address (implicit account or smart contract).
- `contract 'param`: A contract, with the type of its code, contract unit for implicit accounts.
- `key`: A public cryptographic key.
- `key_hash`: The hash of a public cryptographic key.
- `signature`: A cryptographic signature.

  1. What is the difference between `key_hash` and `address`? It seems like for both I can do `PUSH address "tz1..."` and `PUSH key_hash "tz1..."` using the same string literal. I remember seeing something about reveal. What does reveal mean?
  2. Why can I convert between `address` and `contract`. But not between `address` and `key_hash`?
  3. What is the difference between `key` and `key_hash`? When would I have a `key`, but not a `key_hash`?
  4. What is a cryptographic signature and what are some of the use cases in Michelson?
  5. Any other important details about these data types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. `key_hash` is blake2b hash of a public key, in the base58 encoded form it can start only with `tz`, but `address` is more general, it can also hold `KT` accounts;
2. There are no instructions for that, probably because it's a rare and arguable case; EDIT: as pointed out by Raphaël, you can convert `key_hash` to `contract` and then to `address` using `IMPLICIT_ACCOUNT ; ADDRESS`
3. As was mentioned, `key_hash` is blake2b hash of `key`. You would need a `key` for checking a signature for instance;
4. Allow me to link wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EdDSA. A bright example is a multisig contract;
5. Check out the new Michelson documentation https://tezos.gitlab.io/michelson-reference/

To sum up:

- `key` represents a public key (a point on the elliptic curve)
- `key_hash` is blake2b hash of `key`
- `address` is a general representation of Tezos accounts, including both - `tz` and `KT` addresses
- `signature` is a result of signing a message with a private key using the elliptic curve digital signature scheme.

Answer (score 5):

> Why can I convert between address and contract. But not between address and key_hash?

There is the ([`IMPLICIT_ACCOUNT`](https://tezos.gitlab.io/michelson-reference/#instr-IMPLICIT_ACCOUNT)) instruction to go from `key_hash` to `address`. For the other direction, there was ([a feature request](https://gitlab.com/nomadic-labs/tezos/-/merge_requests/93)) but it was closed because no use case has been presented to motivate it.